# HTML <frame> SRC-attribute - use html-code instead of URL

Tags: html, iframe

Is there a way to use pure html-code to display inside a frame instead of having to link to a specific URL/file?

For example:

**NOT like this**

```
<iframe src="left.html" name="left"></iframe>
```

**but like this**

```
<iframe src="here goes the html code" name="thank you SO"></iframe>
```

Comment: No, such thing is not possible by design. What is the point of `<iframe>` if all you want is to have it display static content? Just use `<div>` tag for this.

Comment: see my answer under the other comment! thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "don't have to care about referring & stuff"?

Comment: the problem is that the code I insert somehow referrs my whole page so the code is not displayed INSIDE the div but as a new page..

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you mean. Anyway my first comment stands - you can't put contents inside `<iframe>` that's simply not how it should be used.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

maybe you could inject HTML into the iFrame/Frame like described in this article:[Injecting HTML into an IFrame](http://softwareas.com/injecting-html-into-an-iframe) by Michael Mahemoff.

Something like this:

```
var content = "<html><body><b>Hello World!</b></body></html>";

var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

var frameDoc = iframe.document;
    if(iframe.contentWindow)
        frameDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document; // IE
    // Write into iframe
    frameDoc.open();
    frameDoc.writeln(content);
    frameDoc.close();
```

HTH,

--hennson

Answer (score 1):

In *HTML5* there appears to be a way to do this:

`<iframe seamless sandbox srcdoc="<p>did you get a cover picture yet?"></iframe>`

See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#the-iframe-element), supposedly this is the purpose of the new html5 `srcdoc` attribute.

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe), it appears only chrome will honor the `srcdoc` attribute at this time.

I wasn't able to get this attribute to work, so it's probably not a viable option at this time.  As others suggested, using a `div` is probably a better solution.

Comment: It's currently not supported by any browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you cannot do this.  Maybe you can try with a DIV an modify the content with javascript with innerHTML?

```
<div id='A' onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('A').innerHTML = 'Another content'">
    Click me
<div>
​
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually that was my previous approach but as I wrote in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803700/jquerys-div-html-opens-new-page it doesn't work in this particular case. That is why I wanted to use a frame, so I don't have to care about referring & stuff as all happens inside that frame.

Comment: I did not know the srcdoc attribute, thanks ! But i suspects that it isn't supported for the majority of browsers. I found this information in that page: http://www.html-5.com/tags/iframe-tag/index.html#attributes

Answer (score 0):

srcdoc attribute of iframe is the simple method...

```html
<iframe srcdoc="Your text goes here..."></iframe>
```