# In angularjs, How to embed a complete HTML document?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, iframe, embed

From server, I get a complete HTML document similar to the one below as a `string`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <style>
        body {
            color: #eeeeee;
        }
        h1 {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <p>This is a pargraph</p>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

In angularJS, how to compile this string into an `HTML` document and then display it inside an another one?

Comment: Is an iframe what are you looking for? If so, you could do something similar to this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804739/html-frame-src-attribute-use-html-code-instead-of-url

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before using the **$compile** angular service and directives.

You can reference it at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Here you have some code example

```
app.directive("example", function($compile){
    return{
        link: function(scope, element){
            var t = "<button ng-click='printSomething()'>{{label}}</button>";
            var compFn = $compile(t);
            var content = compFn(scope);
            element.append(content);
        }
    }
});
```

Than you can pass the html string to the directive as:
Instead of `var t = "<button ng-click='printSomething()'>{{label}}` you could pass the html string within your $scope such as

```
  app.directive("example", function($compile){
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {
          htmlString: '=htmlString'
        },
        link: function(scope, element){
            var compFn = $compile(scope.htmlString);
            var content = compFn(scope);
            element.append(content);
        }
    }
});
```

Than your html file content would be:

```
<example html-string="{{htmlString}}"></example>
```

You can also find good guideline for implementing directives in the angular documentation at [Angular Directives Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the **ngBindHtml** directive.

To know in breif about how to use **ngBindHtml** directive refer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Below is an example which uses **ngBindHtml** directive and renders the HTML

```js
(function(){
    angular
        .module('myApp',['ngSanitize'])
        .controller('myCtrl', Controller);
    Controller.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope'];
    function Controller($rootScope, $scope){       
        activate();
        function activate(){
          $scope.html = "<h1>Header</h1><p>This is a pargraph</p>";
        }
    }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <div 
     ng-app="myApp" 
     ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-bind-html="html"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```